# Iterating over basic “for” loop using Handlebars.js

Tags: handlebars.js

I’m new to Handlebars.js and just started using it. Most of the examples are based on iterating over an object. I wanted to know how to use handlebars in basic for loop.

Example.

```
for(i=0 ; i<100 ; i++) {
   create li's with i as the value
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

There's nothing in Handlebars for this but you can add your own helpers easily enough.

If you just wanted to do something `n` times then:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('times', function(n, block) {
    var accum = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        accum += block.fn(i);
    return accum;
});
```

and

```
{{#times 10}}
    <span>{{this}}</span>
{{/times}}
```

If you wanted a whole `for(;;)` loop, then something like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('for', function(from, to, incr, block) {
    var accum = '';
    for(var i = from; i < to; i += incr)
        accum += block.fn(i);
    return accum;
});
```

and

```
{{#for 0 10 2}}
    <span>{{this}}</span>
{{/for}}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/WNbrL/

Comment: +1 for the helpers. As a side note, nesting the for helper won't work in scenarios where you need to refer back to the initial data. i.e data: { rows : 12, cols: 3}.

Comment: When printing `{{../this}}` inside a nested `{{#times}}` block I've noticed that sometimes it will be `[Object object]` instead of the actual numer (one time per nested loop).

Comment: @dude Do you have a runnable example of that? I haven't touched Handlebars for a couple years.

Comment: Inside the loop, I cannot retrieve data from handlebar, do you guys have any ideas about it?

Comment: @HungDQ Sorry but I don't know what you're trying to do, try asking a new question with all the necessary details.

Comment: @muistooshort I've created a new question with necessary details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567260/handlebars-js-iterating-over-for-loop-using-handle-without-losing-data 
Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm getting `expected the second argument to be a number` error

Comment: @MahmoudHeretani You're getting that error from what? Which line?

Comment: from the helper function line {{#times 10}} @muistooshort

Comment: @MahmoudHeretani Which line of the helper? Can you reproduce the error at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Is there a way to get the index of the loop? For example `<span id="thing{{index}}">{{this}}</span>`

Comment: @Longblog Sorry, haven't used Handlebars in years so I'm not sure. You could compute the index yourself given `this` and the loop's `from` and `incr` or perhaps call the `block.fn` with an object containing whatever you need.

Answer (score 26):

Top answer here is good, if you want to use last / first / index though you could use the following

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('times', function(n, block) {
    var accum = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        block.data.index = i;
        block.data.first = i === 0;
        block.data.last = i === (n - 1);
        accum += block.fn(this);
    }
    return accum;
});
```

and

```
{{#times 10}}
    <span> {{@first}} {{@index}} {{@last}}</span>
{{/times}}
```

Comment: This helper seems to not allow to use @../index or @../last when coming to nested uses of the Helper. Is this right or maybe I did something wrong?

Answer (score 9):

If you like CoffeeScript

```
Handlebars.registerHelper "times", (n, block) ->
  (block.fn(i) for i in [0...n]).join("")
```

and

```
{{#times 10}}
  <span>{{this}}</span>
{{/times}}
```

Answer (score 9):

This snippet will take care of else block in case `n` comes as dynamic value, and provide `@index` optional context variable, it will keep the outer context of the execution as well.

```
/*
* Repeat given markup with given times
* provides @index for the repeated iteraction
*/
Handlebars.registerHelper("repeat", function (times, opts) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    var data = {};

    if ( times ) {
        for ( i = 0; i < times; i += 1 ) {
            data.index = i;
            out += opts.fn(this, {
                data: data
            });
        }
    } else {

        out = opts.inverse(this);
    }

    return out;
});
```

Comment: I like this approach better because you have the @index variable at hand. Also you can easily add other variables depending on specific needs.

Answer (score 8):

Couple of years late, but there's now `each` available in Handlebars which allows you to iterate pretty easily over an array of items.

https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each