# Using data in a handlebars helper

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js, client-side-templating

I'm trying to write a Handlebars helper that lets me display an element `x` number of times, where `x` is defined in the data passed to the template.

I'm adapting the code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924452/handlebar-js-iterating-over-for-basic-loop) for `#times`. But instead of it running a constant number of times for each template, I want to be able to control that with the data I pass to the template.

This is a contrived example, but if I passed in `{stars: 50}` to this template, I'd want it to print 50 stars.

```
{{#times {{stars}} }}★{{/times}}
```

This obviously isn't the right way to do this as I get a parse error when compiling the template.

`Expecting 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'ID', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'OPEN'`

But how do I let my helpers accept dynamic input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I feel silly. You can just use the variables directly without the brackets. So the proper way to do it is like this:

```
{{#times stars}}★{{/times}}
```