# handlebars js - iterate n times and access array data if available

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

So my problem is the following : I have an array of `things`, whose count is dynamic.

Now what I need, is in my template, to iterate 100 times, displaying a 100 rows ; and if things[i] exists, then display it on the row.

So I could do the basic iterator with [mu is too short's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11924998/150015). However in the {{#times}} loop I can't reference my things table by using the `this` index.

That is, if I write `{{../things.[0]}}`, it works (it displays the value) ; however with `{{../things.[this]}}`, it doesn't anymore.

Any idea how to do this ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you could jsfiddle the code. I expect `this` being now a `Number`. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand, why don't you do:

```
{{#each things}}
  {{this}} //Here is your row
{{/each}}
```

Or do you need exactly to loop 100 times and display empty row if data does not exists? If so, then this may help(`times` helper was taken from your reference):

```
{{#times 100}}
  {{lookup ../things this}}
{{/times}}
```

If you have old version of handlebars without `lookup` helper, here is a source of it https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/handlebars/helpers/lookup.js