# looping n times with Handlebars

Tags: html, node.js, handlebars.js

> there is already an answer here
>   [Iterating over basic “for” loop using Handlebars.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924452/iterating-over-basic-for-loop-using-handlebars-js/11924998#11924998)
>   but it's from **2012** so maybe I can get a better solution now.

I want to loop n times. If there are 5 containers to create I want to loop 5 times.

I render my template with NodeJs and try to pass a count variable

```
res.render('myTemplate', {
   barCount: 3
});
```

Currently I have to write

```
<div class="container">
</div>
<div id="bar3" class="bar"></div>

<div class="container">
</div>
<div id="bar2" class="bar"></div>

<div class="container">
</div>
<div id="bar1" class="bar"></div>
```

But I would like to write something like this

```
    {{#each barCount}}
        <div class="container"></div>        
        <div id="bar{{barCount - this + 1}}" class="bar"></div>
    {{/each}}
```

Do I still have to use a helper?

Comment: What the problem to read documentation?)

Answer (score 1):

```
res.render('myTemplate', {
  barCount: [3, 2, 1] // or use lodash range function
});

{{#each barCount}}
    <div class="container"></div>        
    <div id="bar{{this}}" class="bar"></div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: ye I thought about it but `barCount: [3, 2, 1]` might end in spaghetti code.. dunno