# Handlebars.js iterating over for loop using Handle without losing data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handlebars.js

I'm trying to iterate over "for" loop using Handlebars.js, but inside the loop, I cannot retrieve data passed to the template. Here is how I tried:

For the loop function:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('for', function (from, to, incr, block) {
  var accum = '';
  for (var i = from; i < to; i += incr)
    accum += block.fn(i);
  return accum;
});
```

Template file:

```
{{#for 0 10 2}}
 <tr>
  <td class="p-0">
   <input class="form-control" data-position="B5_{{id}}_{{B5.id}}" type="text" {{#if B5.isReadOnly}} readonly {{/if}} value="{{B5.value}}"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
{{/for}}
```

Inside the loop, I cannot retrieve {{id}} or {{B5.id}}, which normally works outside.

Here is how I pass data to the template:

```
 export function renderSheet(template, data) {
      try {
        return Handlebars.compile(template)(data);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Please help me figure out what is wrong here. I'd be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Thank a comment, I have now can access data inside the loop, but I got another problem which is how do I get current "i" value inside the for loop?. For example:

```
{{#each @root.A5.value}}
```

How can I replace 5 with current i value?

Comment: can kindly share the data too?

Comment: I've just updated the question with the detail of the data variable

Comment: Solution to your problem can be found at this URL - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12297980/8566595

Comment: Thank you, I can retrieve data by using root, but there is another problem that I've just updated in the detail.